# Can I download a WSDL document with just SOAP 1.1?

Tags: soap, wsdl, asmx, salesforce

I'm trying to import a WSDL document that only supports SOAP 1.1 (Salesforce.com, WSDL to APEX)

However, the WSDL at the endpoint contains definitions for SOAP 1.1 and 1.2.

Is it possible to pass an argument to the .asmx service to return only the 1.1 specifications or do I need to manually remove the 1.2 references myself?

Comment: what spec of soap you want to really work with?

Comment: I want to work with SOAP 1.1 ~ is that what your referring too when you say spec?

Answer (score 1):

Often it's easy enough to strip down the WSDL to just keep the Soap 1.1 bindings. If you open it up in a text editor you'll see lots sections are doubled up, one of each will have `soap11` and the other `soap12`.

Delete all the `soap12` parts and you should be good to go. If possible, post the contents here (if they're not too long or private) and I might be able to help you cut it down.